# How to get last character of a string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a SELECT statement that creates a new column where if a field called "string" ends with the letter A, B, or F it gets the value "Ok" otherwise it gets the value "No".

I know I need to do some substring but cannot get it right.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`RIGHT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx):

```
SELECT Result = CASE WHEN RIGHT(string, 1) IN ('A','B','F') 
                THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'No' END
```

Answer (score 12):

This could to the trick

```
select right('abc', 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

---

Query the list of CITY names ending with vowels (a, e, i, o, u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE Right(CITY,1)  IN
('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work,

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(50)
SET @STR='DFGDFGF'
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT RIGHT(@STR, 1)) = 'A' THEN 'OK'
WHEN (SELECT RIGHT(@STR, 1)) = 'B' THEN 'OK'
WHEN (SELECT RIGHT(@STR, 1)) = 'F' THEN 'OK'
ELSE 'NOT OK' END
```